# Laravel4 Eloquent error when i fetch a Model relationship and then try an update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
<?php


class Test extends Eloquent  {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'foo';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function item() {
        return $this->hasOne('Entity', 'tid');
    }


}


<?php


class Entity extends Eloquent  {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'entity';

}

Route::get('foo', function() {
    // Assume we fetch one object, just to send it back to the client.
    $foo = \Test::find(1);
    // Lazy load item.
    $foo->item;

    // This run fine.
    $foo->save();

    return $foo;
}

Route::put('foo', function() {
    // Then, assume we receive the very same object in a json POST or PUT.
    $foo = new Test($inputArray);

    // Since we forced the 'item' property in the model, we receive back an SQL exception.
    $foo->save();
});
```

`$foo->save()` triggers an exception that claims

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'item' in 'field list'`.

How to solve this?

**== EDIT ==**

Added more code. I'm sorry the previous question did not point the problem precisely, i realized this later.

Long story short: if i load related models the Eloquent way, then Laravel is aware that the `item` property doesn't need to be saved.

If i put arbitrary values in that very same property, Laravel is not aware and tries to store values. This could be as per design, anyway i find this to be a really common scenario in a rest architecture, where basically i can re-POST or re-PUT data as i received from the server.

So, again, how to solve this (other than unsetting $inputArray['item'] each time, of course)?

Comment: Is that your full model?

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here.  what is the result of vardump on $test after you call the find method?

Comment: Added more code, check it out

Answer (score 0):

What you are presenting is a MySQL error message. So probably Laravel is doing what you told it to do, but you don't have the necessary schema in your MySQL database to provide what it needs, to be successful. Check your model Item and table items.